# SpatiaLite: dumpkml with name and description

Tags: kml, spatialite

How does one get the optional arguments in .dumpkml working? According to the .help .dumpkml should work like this:

> .dumpkml table_name geom_column kml_path [precision] [name_column] [desc_column]

I can get it working with

> .dumpkml table geom table.kml

But every point is just called 'name' and when I try:

> .dumpkml table geom table.kml name_column=column

All I do is lose the geometry (x,y=0,0) and everything still gets called 'name' rather than the value within the specified column.

Any assistance appreciated,
Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are positional, not named.

So if you want to specify the name_column, you have to specify the precision. If you want to specify the desc_column, you have to specify the precision and the name_column.

Here is an example:

```
bradh@ornata:~/devel/spatialite/libspatialite-work/test/sql_stmt_tests$ spatialite testdb1.sqlite 
SpatiaLite version ..: 3.1.0-RC2        Supported Extensions:
        - 'VirtualShape'        [direct Shapefile access]
        - 'VirtualDbf'          [direct DBF access]
        - 'VirtualXL'           [direct XLS access]
        - 'VirtualText'         [direct CSV/TXT access]
        - 'VirtualNetwork'      [Dijkstra shortest path]
        - 'RTree'               [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
        - 'MbrCache'            [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
        - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
        - 'VirtualFDO'          [FDO-OGR interoperability]
        - 'SpatiaLite'          [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 version ......: Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009
GEOS version ........: 3.3.2-CAPI-1.7.2
SQLite version ......: 3.7.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
spatialite> .tables
SpatialIndex            geometry_columns_auth   roads_net_data        
alpha_roads             idx_roads_geom          spatial_ref_sys       
alpha_roads_net         idx_roads_geom_node     spatialite_history    
alpha_roads_net_data    idx_roads_geom_parent   views_geometry_columns
data1                   idx_roads_geom_rowid    virts_geometry_columns
geom_cols_ref_sys       roads                 
geometry_columns        roads_net             
spatialite> .headers on
spatialite> .schema alpha_roads
CREATE TABLE alpha_roads(
  id,
  geom NUM,
  node_from,
  node_to
);
CREATE TRIGGER "ggi_alpha_roads_geom" BEFORE INSERT ON "alpha_roads"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'alpha_roads.geom violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
WHERE (SELECT type FROM geometry_columns
WHERE f_table_name = 'alpha_roads' AND f_geometry_column = 'geom'
AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."geom", type, srid, 'XY') = 1) IS NULL;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER "ggu_alpha_roads_geom" BEFORE UPDATE ON "alpha_roads"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'alpha_roads.geom violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
WHERE (SELECT type FROM geometry_columns
WHERE f_table_name = 'alpha_roads' AND f_geometry_column = 'geom'
AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."geom", type, srid, 'XY') = 1) IS NULL;
END;

spatialite> select id,astext(geom) from alpha_roads limit 5;
id|astext(geom)
ARC_2|LINESTRING(11.207073 42.436534, 11.207147 42.436522)
ARC_3|LINESTRING(11.207147 42.436522, 11.207224 42.436518, 11.207629 42.436342, 11.207864 42.436236, 11.208152 42.436198)
ARC_4|LINESTRING(11.208152 42.436198, 11.209313 42.436293, 11.209607 42.436343)
ARC_5|LINESTRING(11.209607 42.436343, 11.210469 42.436489)
ARC_6|LINESTRING(11.210469 42.436489, 11.211013 42.436625)
spatialite> .dumpkml alpha_roads geom foo.kml 5 id
```

Which will give you something that starts like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_2</name><description>description</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20707,42.43653 11.20715,42.43652</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_3</name><description>description</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20715,42.43652 11.20722,42.43652 11.20763,42.43634 11.20786,42.43624 11.20815,42.4362</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_4</name><description>description</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20815,42.4362 11.20931,42.43629 11.20961,42.43634</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_5</name><description>description</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20961,42.43634 11.21047,42.43649</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_6</name><description>description</description><LineString><coordinates>11.21047,42.43649 11.21101,42.43662</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
```

If you want to get a real description, you can use the extra element:

```
spatialite> .dumpkml alpha_roads geom foo.kml 5 id node_from
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_2</name><description>NODE_1</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20707,42.43653 11.20715,42.43652</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_3</name><description>NODE_2</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20715,42.43652 11.20722,42.43652 11.20763,42.43634 11.20786,42.43624 11.20815,42.4362</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_4</name><description>NODE_3</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20815,42.4362 11.20931,42.43629 11.20961,42.43634</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
        <Placemark><name>ARC_5</name><description>NODE_4</description><LineString><coordinates>11.20961,42.43634 11.21047,42.43649</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
```

It might look slight different on your machine, since this is a wierd out of date, pre-release with devel changes machine :-)